# Can't connect to my Wordpress website using Windows 8 app?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, json, windows

Im trying to connect to my Wordpress site (self hosted) through the Windows 8 app. First, after giving the Wordpress.com account details, it show my site and ask me to Authorize. after authorizing, it say "Can't connect to the service". I have used several security plugins in wordpress like the Better WP Security. But they block the old method of connecting. I think Jetpack have added a new way. Is there anything wrong with my PC?

Comment: Why are you connecting to your self-hosted WordPress using WordPress.com credentials?

Comment: Its connected through Jetpack... On connecting, its asking for Wordpress.com credentials

Comment: Are you able to connect to your WordPress (self-hosted) site with your WordPress.com credentials using any other apps which use XML-RPC?

Comment: @SahasKatta Can you please tell me another app so I can try?

Comment: @SahasKatta I just tried the Android app. It doesn't use the Wordpress.com credentials but let us give the site URL and the local user name password. That app connected successfully to my blog!

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at the WordPress app for Windows 8. It looks as though it is strictly built for WordPress.com, not self-hosted blogs.

The apps available for Android, iOS, and Windows Phone on the other hand actually support both self-hosted installations and WordPress.com.

Even though you integrated some WordPress.com services into your blog via JetPack, it unfortunately doesn't magically make it compatible.

Until the folks at Automattic update the Windows 8 app, I would suggest using either Word 2013 or Windows Live Writer if you are looking for a native blogging experience. Both of these programs support publishing to self-hosted WordPress installations out of the box.

Comment: I think I can remember them announcing support for self hosted blogs also...

Comment: Nope. See my answer below and their store page details.

Comment: No! Not MS Word; never use it!

Answer (score 1):

It's only for .com installations. Here's a quote from their store page:

> **Description**
>
> Browse the best original content on WordPress.com, including articles
>   and photography on travel, art, entertainment, food, and much more.
>   Sign in with your WordPress.com account to read blogs you follow and
>   easily share cool content you find on the web by reblogging it on your
>   WordPress.com site.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Browse the best original content on WordPress.com
> - Create new posts and publish them to your WordPress.com blog in an instant
> - Share photos, links, and quotes from any app on your WordPress.com blog